# Infinite product of sine function

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does this the sequence go to zero?

$\Pi_{n=1}^{N}\text{sin}(2\pi n\omega)$ as N $\rightarrow \infty$  for any $\omega \in (0,1)?$

I can see this sequence is always decreasing for general $\omega$. And for some specific $\omega$ (in $\mathbb{Q}$ I believe), sin($2\pi n_0\omega$) becomes 0 for some specific $n_0$ so making the sequence to be 0 there after. But how to show such sequence goes to zero for general $\omega \in (0,1)$ though?

Comment: See "help" above to find what sort of questions to ask here.

Comment: Hint: Kronecker's theorem for $\omega\not\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Fan Zheng - what theorem do you mean exactly?